# When I run Android project all components land on top of each other

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm very new to Android Studio and I'm trying to make my 1st app, where you enter 2 numbers and it adds them together. I'm having an issue with all the view components, because in the studio they look fine, but when run they all land on top of each other. I believe this is because I haven't added constraints, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. Thanks!
[image: In studio]
[image: The view on my phone]

Comment: you haven't added any constraints to your components (see the red triangle next to each component as a warning)

Comment: @a_local_nobody thanks I'll add some

Comment: you can't simply drag and drop components and expect them to be as shown in the editor with constraint layout, you'll always have to add constraints to make them stay there - not trying to rant, just explaining :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **Component Tree** (bottom left of your image) you can see that all your views have a red circle to the right. You can see what kind of error you have hovering the mouse on top of it.

In this case, it seems you haven't set constraints.

When using Constraint Layout you have to define at least 2 constraints for each view. A vertical one (top or bottom) and a horizontal one (left or right). Without these constraints the IDE is unable to find a position to set the view to, so by default they all go to the top left.